# Plotting hyperbolic trigonometric function with TikZ

Tags: tikz-pgf, pgfplots, graphs

everyone.

I've been trying to plot the modes shapes of a beam according to the following equation:

[image: Mode shape equation of a free-free beam]

Where βn*L is 0 for n = 0, 4.7300 for n = 1, 7.8532 for n = 2 and so on.

I should be getting the following graph (which I've plotted using mathcha.io):

[image: Ideal results]

But, what I've been able to get, so far, is this mess (plotted using TikZ)

[image: wrong plot]

Using the following code:

```
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\pgfplotsset{compat=1.16}

\begin{tikzpicture}
   \begin{axis}[
   xlabel = $x$,
   ylabel = $w(x)$,
   xmin = 0,xmax = 1,
   %ymin = 0,ymax = 8,
   domain = 0:1,
   smooth,thick,
   axis lines = middle,
   every axis x label/.style={at={(current axis.right of origin)},anchor=west},
   every tick/.style = {thick}]

   \addplot[color=purple]{(sinh(4.73*x)+sin(4.73*x))+(sin(4.73)-sinh(4.73))/(cosh(4.73)-cos(4.73))*(cosh(4.73*x)+cos(4.73*x))};
   \addplot[color=red]{(sinh(7.85*x)+sin(7.85*x))+(sin(7.85)-sinh(7.85))/(cosh(7.85)-cos(7.85))*(cosh(7.85*x)+cos(7.85*x))};
   \addplot[color=orange]{(sinh(11*x)+sin(11*x))+(sin(11)-sinh(11))/(cosh(11)-cos(11))*(cosh(11*x)+cos(11*x))};

   \end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
```

Maybe I'm not too familiar with the TikZ syntax, but I just can't get it to work properly for me.

If anyone can point me in the right direction, that would be great!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

By deafult, PGFplots takes angles in degrees. In order to pass angles as radians, you should use: `trig format=rad` as an option for the `axis` environment.

```
\documentclass[border=5pt]{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\pgfplotsset{compat=1.16}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
  \begin{axis}[
    trig format=rad, % HERE
    xlabel = $x$,
    ylabel = $w(x)$,
    xmin = 0,xmax = 1,
    % ymin = 0,ymax = 8,
    domain = 0:1,
    smooth,thick,
    axis lines = middle,
    every axis x label/.style={at={(current axis.right of origin)},anchor=west},
    every tick/.style = {thick}]

    \addplot[color=purple]{(sinh(4.73*x)+sin(4.73*x))+(sin(4.73)-sinh(4.73))/(cosh(4.73)-cos(4.73))*(cosh(4.73*x)+cos(4.73*x))};
    \addplot[color=red]{(sinh(7.85*x)+sin(7.85*x))+(sin(7.85)-sinh(7.85))/(cosh(7.85)-cos(7.85))*(cosh(7.85*x)+cos(7.85*x))};
    \addplot[color=orange]{(sinh(11*x)+sin(11*x))+(sin(11)-sinh(11))/(cosh(11)-cos(11))*(cosh(11*x)+cos(11*x))};

  \end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

The grid and the rest of the formatting is left as an exercise.

Comment: That it! Just tested it and worked correctly.

Thank you!